# How can I store the data extracted from the database in an array using the prepared statement method and then export it as JSON _incode using php?

Tags: php, jquery

I have a select input field and I print the extracted data using a foreach loop normally in the options field. I am trying to store the data extracted from the database in an array using PHP prepared statement method, and then export this file as a JSON incode file to use later when generating a new dynamic select field. The issue I am facing is that the data only appears in the original select input field and does not show in the newly generated dynamic select fields, showing only the word 'undefined'. Any help from you would be highly appreciated and valued.

```
<select class="form-control select_acount js-example-basic-single"id="validationTooltip01" name="account[]"required>
  <option value="">--إختر الحساب--</option>
    <?php                            
      $stmt = $con->prepare("select * from categories WHERE parent_id != ? And status =? And company = ?");
      $a = 0;
      $b = 0;                                
      $stmt->bind_param('iis',$a,$b,$_SESSION["company"]);
      $stmt->execute();
      $result=$stmt->get_result();
      $data[]=array();
          foreach($result as $row){?>
          $data[]=$row;
          echo '<option value="<?php echo $row['acc_name'];?>"><?php echo $row['acc_name'];?></option>';
          }
      <?php } ?>  
      $stmt->close();
      $con->close();  
</select>
```

```
<script>
  
  var data = <?php echo json_encode($data); ?>;
      var product_dd = "";
          product_dd += '<select class="form-control select_acount js-example-basic-single" name="account[]"required>';
          product_dd += '<option value="">--إختر الحساب--</option>';
      if(data.length > 0){
        for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i ++) {
          product_dd += `<option value="${data[i]['acc_name']}">${data[i]['acc_name']}</option>`;
        }
      }
         product_dd += "</select>";
      
      var i = 0;
      $("#add-btn").click(function() {
        ++i;
        
        $("#dynamicAddRemove").append('<tr><td class="td">'+product_dd+'</td></tr>');
        $('.js-example-basic-single').select2();
      });
      
</script>
```

Comment: When you debug the second code snippet, what does `data` actually contain in the client-side code?

Comment: @David In the original first row, the data appears well, but in the new generated row, no data appears and only the word Undefined is given. You can see the result in the following image:(https://b.top4top.io/p_3006yv34g1.jpg)

Comment: Then now would be a good time for you to do some debugging.  In particular, you should examine the client-side code produced by your PHP code, examine the actual data in the `data` variable, and use your browser's script debugger to step through this code and observe the actual values being used.

Comment: @David You can see the result in the first row how well it looks:(https://c.top4top.io/p_3006gny5f1.png)

Comment: That's all well and good, but just sharing pictures of your website is not the same thing as debugging your code.  If you're not familiar with what debugging is or how to use your browser's development/debugging tools, now is the time for you to start.

Comment: @David Thank you. I discovered the error and corrected it. : `$rows = [];
foreach($result as $row){ $rows[] = $row;`  `<?php echo json_encode($rows); ?>;`